# How to reposition a node in XML with DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom

So I have this wich should put into an xml file a movie.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse("D:\\College\\Java Eclipse\\tema5\\Movies\\Movies.xml");


  try {
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Movie");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    // firstname elements
    Element id = doc.createElement("Id");
    id.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("3"));
    rootElement.appendChild(id);

    // lastname elements
    Element name = doc.createElement("Name");
    name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Movie 3"));
    rootElement.appendChild(name);

    // nickname elements
    Element category = doc.createElement("Category");
    category.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Animation"));
    rootElement.appendChild(category);

    // salary elements
    Element releasedate = doc.createElement("ReleaseDate");
    releasedate.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("10-Jun-2012"));
    rootElement.appendChild(releasedate);


    Element rating = doc.createElement("Rating");
    rating.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("10"));
    rootElement.appendChild(rating);

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\College\\Java Eclipse\\tema5\\Movies\\Movies.xml"));

    // Output to console for testing
    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);



  } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
    tfe.printStackTrace();

  }
```

The problem is that in my xml file I already have two movies, when it tries to put the third one it succeeds but at the forth one it dies. I think it's because of the nodes and I want to know how to reposition the last  to the end of the file so I can place more movies. This is the xml doc after the first insertion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Movie>  
<Movie>
    <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Movie 1</Name>
    <Category>Action</Category>
    <ReleaseDate>22-JUN-2010</ReleaseDate>
    <Rating>9</Rating>
</Movie>
<Movie>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Movie 2</Name>
    <Category>Comedy</Category>
    <ReleaseDate>2-JUN-2011</ReleaseDate>
    <Rating>8</Rating>
</Movie>

</Movie>
<Movie>
<Id>3</Id>
<Name>Movie 3</Name>
<Category>Animation</Category>
<ReleaseDate>10-Jun-2012</ReleaseDate>
<Rating>10</Rating>
</Movie>
```

Comment: what do you mean by dies. If it is your origina xml that is malformatted (dbl closing movie tag)

Comment: /Movies.xml; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 10; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.    i think it has to be like this <movie> <movie></movie>...<movie></movie></movie>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Element docRoot = doc.getDocumentElement();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Movie");
docRoot.appendChild(rootElement);
```

I would suggest renaming your rootElement variable to newMovie as it is missleading. You can only have one root element in xml, and you get it by doc.getDocumentElement()